# How can I get git to select txt files in the current directory alone

Tags: wildcards, git

How do I select all the files ending with `.txt` in the current directory, but omit all the ones in the subdirectories?

`*.txt` selects all the files ending in `.txt` in the subdirectories as well. How do I omit them?

**directory structure:**

```
current folder
|-first_file.txt
|-sub_folder
  |-second_file
```

I'm trying to add the first_file alone to a git repository. But doing `git add *.txt` adds both the first and the second file to the stage. I want only the first_file to be added.

Comment: How exactly are you using the pattern (please add whole command/relevant part of the script)? Which shell are you using?

Comment: Updated the content.

Comment: please add the **exact** git command you are running to your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between whether the shell or git handle the pattern. `git` considers subdirectories as well, the shell doesn't. So in your case, running

```
git add *.txt
```

while the current directory is your "current folder" lets the shell do the wildcard expansion (and therefore only adds matching files in the current directory).

---

To elaborate

- With `git add *.txt` wildcard expansion is done by the shell, so `git` actually gets called with `git add file1.txt file2.txt` (which means that `git` just takes the file names passed and adds them). Only caveat here is that if there are *no* files matching `*.txt` `git` gets run as `git add *.txt` nevertheless which of course will trigger `git`s subdirectory scan
- With `git add '*.txt'` wildcard expansion is done by `git` which always implies a subdirectory scan as well.

Comment: oops, okay. So how do I omit the subdirectory?

Comment: are you quoting `*.txt` or escaping the `*`?  if so, don't.

Comment: btw, this is pretty much the example in `git add --help` (search for EXAMPLES).  Amongst other things, t tells you "*....Because this example lets the shell expand the asterisk (i.e. you are listing the files explicitly), it does not consider subdir/git-foo.sh*".   Note, though, that as per standard shell behaviour if `*.txt` doesn't match any files in the current directory, it will be passed to `git` as a literal string.

Comment: @hello_rocker_dot_com If you run the command as shown in the answer, subdirectories will *not* be considered because the expansion is done by the shell (which does only look in the current directory). I've extended the answer a bit.

Comment: I need to have a reputation of 15 :D I will do it once I reach that :)